# jquery selector and setInterval

Tags: jquery, selector

```js
$('#start').click(function() {
  setInterval(fade, 1000);

  function fade() {
    $('.visible:first-child').removeClass('visible').addClass('invisible');
  };
});
```

```css
.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <span class='visible'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</span>
  <span class='visible'> consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
  <span class='visible'> Integer nec odio.</span>
</p>
<button id="start">start</button>
```

I want the `<span>` tags to be faded out in sequence.

To do that, I set the script that change class of `<span>` tags at an interval of 1000 ms.

But it only works once.

I think it's because `.visible:first-child` is never changed.

https://jsfiddle.net/dewit/b9Lgdwaj/

Comment: You need to go through them one by one - this should help http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `first` instead of `first-child`.

working snippet below.

```js
$('#start').click(function(){
    setInterval(fade,1000);
    function fade(){
        $('.visible:first').removeClass('visible').addClass('invisible');
    };
});
```

```css
.invisible {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
    <span class='visible'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</span>
    <span class='visible'> consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
    <span class='visible'> Integer nec odio.</span>
</p>

<button id="start">start</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

first-child selector selects all elements that are the first child of their parent. That's why your only first element was invisible. You can use $('.visible:first') for this.

Answer (score 1):

":first-child" always means the first child of a node, not including selectors. So when you query ".visible:first-child" you'll yield no results if the first child is not ".visible". You'll need to change your query to account for this.